# bash - remove the last part of a string

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I want to know the ruby version being run from a bash script.

That can be done with `ruby -v`:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24) [i686-linux] Brightbox
```

My problem is that I just want the version number. How do I transform that output into this?

```
1.9.3p545
```

Comment: Is the `p545` important? If not, you could do `ruby -e 'puts RUBY_VERSION'`

Comment: @TomFenech cool!. Without newline character `ruby -e '$><<RUBY_VERSION'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through cut,

```
$ ruby -v | cut -d" " -f2
1.9.3p484
```

Through awk,

```
$ ruby -v | awk '{print $2}'
1.9.3p484
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ruby -v | cut -d' ' -f2
```

Answer (score 2):

Some solutions use `awk` or `cut`, those waste a child process.  Try this:

```
read p ver rest < <(ruby -v)
echo $ver
```

`$p` will contain `ruby`, and `$rest` the trailing fields.  This solution only uses one child process (ruby), not two.